# Using $_FILES to check if a file has been uploaded

Tags: php

In a form, I have two file inputs (`handImg` and `picImg`). The form will allow the user to upload an image to only **one** of these file inputs. I have the following PHP script to check which file input was used and sets the appropriate values.

```
if(isset($_FILES['handImg']['tmp_name'])){
    $img = $_FILES['handImg'];
    $material = $_POST['handmaterial'];
    $size = $_POST['handsize'];
    $color = $_POST['handcolor'];
    $title = $_POST['handtitle'];
    $desc = $_POST['handdesc'];
    $profit = $_POST['handprofit'];
    $price = $_POST['handcalcprice'];
    $type = "HandMade";
}

if(isset($_FILES['picImg']['tmp_name'])){
    $img = $_FILES['picImg'];
    $material = $_POST['picmaterial'];
    $size = $_POST['picsize'];
    $color = $_POST['piccolor'];
    $title = $_POST['pictitle'];
    $desc = $_POST['picdesc'];
    $profit = $_POST['picprofit'];
    $price = $_POST['piccalcprice'];
    $type = "Photo";
}
```

This doesn't work properly. The first if statement always passes, no matter which file input was selected.

I've searched and tried different solutions like replacing `isset` with `is_uploaded_file` or `file_exists`, but both gave the same result. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `empty ()` instead of `isset ()`?

Comment: @wayneOS Just tried it. That did the trick. Do you know why isset() didn't work?

Comment: `isset` means the key exists in the assoc array, `empty` inspects the key's contents (the value)

Comment: @user633183 Awesome. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @JaxonCrosmas when a form with an file-input gets send the $_FILES variables will be set but are emtpy. therefore your check for existens is true although it is empty.

Comment: I'd go with `empty()` as suggested along with `is_uploaded_file()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php - You probably have a value in the form's input that should have been posted, IMHO.